# how do I group parameters with JSDoc like lodash?

Tags: javascript, parameters, jsdoc

I want to know how ***lodash*** can group suggestions for parameters on the functions they have based on the type or number of parameters that users enter as shown below:


[image]


in the picture above, it can be seen that there are **8 groupings** of suggestions on the `each` function in ***lodash***. and below is a sample code in my case:

**Example function:**

```
function filter(allowSize, max) {
  //do Something
}
```

**If `filter` function just have 1 parameter, use jsdoc below:**

```
/**
 * @param {object} allowSize
 * @param {number} allowSize.min
 * @param {number} allowSize.max
 */
```

> I want to remove **`max`** parameter from suggestion, but I don't know how
>   to do it

**If `filter` function have 2 parameter, use jsdoc below:**

```
/**
 * @param {number} allowSize
 * @param {number} max
 */
```

> I want to rename **`allowSize`** parameter to **`min`** in suggestion, but I don't
>   know how to do it

how do I do the above using **jsdoc**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **function overload** method, but javascript does not support this method.Then how do you do the *lodash* ?

the answer is *lodash* using typescript to write their code.Typescript allows you to write functions using the overload method.Typescript will generate a file with the extension `.d.ts` which contains information related to the code written.

**Example:**

```
function filter(allowSize: object): any;
function filter(min: number, max: number): any;
function filter(arg1: object | number, arg2?: number): any {
    if (typeof arg1 === "object") {
        // do something when the function only have 1 parameter
    } else if (typeof arg1 === "number" && typeof arg2 === "number") {
        // do something when the function has 2 parameters
    } else {
        // default
    }
}
```

after that, compile the TS file with the command `tsc -d typescript_file.ts`

the `-d` parameter is useful for telling the compiler to create a declaration file.